# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to run Python interpreter in Terminal

Tags: python

I'm getting the following error when I try to run Python in Terminal:

```bash
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joshlee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 541, in <module> 
    main()
  File "/Users/joshlee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 522, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/Users/joshlee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 282, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/Users/joshlee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 258, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/Users/joshlee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 248, in getuserbase 
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/Users/joshlee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 601, in get_config_var 
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/Users/joshlee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 550, in get_config_vars 
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/Users/joshlee/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sysconfig.py", line 421, in _init_posix 
    _temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), ['build_time_vars'], 0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m_darwin_darwin'
```

I haven't touched Python in a while, and now I'm getting this error. What's going on here?

Comment: the imported module seems to be not within the scope of your application.  Also, if you dont want to reference the method through the parent module name, you can use: `from module import *` in order to add functions to the current running instance.  if you do: `import x` you would need to reference via `x.myfunction(5)`

Comment: @Fallenreaper the error is not being thrown in the OP's own code.

Comment: It looks like this might be related to https://bugs.python.org/issue28046 but I can't say for sure.

Comment: I deleted the Anaconda3 repository, and regular Python seems to be working. I'm just going to forget this ever happened.

Comment: I think a better approach would have been to at least try update Anaconda, since you may have just ditched a lot of libraries you need for your code. If you don't do much dev work in Python, maybe not.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time, thank you. I'm a Python beginner so I doubt I'll miss anything much - I don't even remember installing Anaconda.

Comment: What's in your `PYTHONPATH`?